# Trigger bidireccional

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo que realizar dos triggers, uno que, después de insertar en test1, inserte en test2. Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema que tengo es que debo hacer lo mismo en el caso inverso. Cuando hay un insert en test2, debo hacer el mismo insert en test1. Entiendo que el error que tengo es que puedo entrar en un bucle infinito, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna posibilidad de solucionar esto:

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `ai_test1_test2` AFTER INSERT ON `test1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN INSERT INTO test2 (vtest2) VALUES (new.vtest1)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

En el insert bidireccional sería:

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `ai_test2_test1` AFTER INSERT ON `test2` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN INSERT INTO test1 (vtest1) VALUES (new.vtest2)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pero en qué momento es que quieres que deje de insertar datos? No veo como puedas evitar un bucle infinito en este caso.

Comment: Gracias @AdrianaHernández, ya he comprobado que es imposible realizarlo de esta manera. Antes de hacer más pruebas pensé que la ejecución de cada trigger era independiente y que no ejecutaba el proceso de otros triggers dependientes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una solución al problema, quizás no sea la más eficiente pero puedo salir del bucle de triggers.

Se basa en la identificación común para una misma tupla en las dos tablas, así que por su clave primaria podría ver si existen en la otra tabla, si no existe la crea, si existe, no realiza acción y sale del trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `ai_test1_test2` AFTER INSERT ON `test1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT vtest2 FROM test2 WHERE vtest2 = new.vtest1 ) THEN
    INSERT INTO test2 (vtest2) VALUES (new.vtest1)
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `ai_test2_test1` AFTER INSERT ON `test1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT vtest1 FROM test1 WHERE vtest1 = new.vtest2 ) THEN
    INSERT INTO test1 (vtest1) VALUES (new.vtest2)
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas hacer no es crear un `trigger` sino un `procedimiento almacenado` y en lugar de hacer los `INSERT` directo a esas tablas, ejecuta el procedimiento con los parámetros que necesites.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Replica_Tabla2 (param1 VARCHAR(10), ..., paramN INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test2 (vtest2) VALUES (param1, ...);
END
$$
```

y lo llamas con:

```
CALL Replica_Tabla2 ('ID', ..., 5);
```

Te dejo apuntes al respecto: [Procedimientos almacenados y funciones](http://manuales.guebs.com/mysql-5.0/stored-procedures.html#create-procedure).

Comment: Suena interesante, aunque aún no veo del todo como me podría solucionar este problema. Por lo que veo, deberia: 
- Crear el PA.
- Pasarle argumentos al PA.

Pero, de donde obtengo estos argumentos para pasarselos al PA?
Muchas gracias, saludos!!

Comment: Vale, creo que se me ha ocurrido una cosa gracias a tu comentario. Puedo crear un PA, ejecutar uno de los triggers, y una vez haga el insert, llamar a el PA que hará la insercción en la segunda tabla pasándole a ese PA los datos obtenidos de ejecutar el primer trigger...

Comment: No sé si sea lo mejor pero definitivamente es una opción que puede servir.